# How to solve a UnicodeDecodeError?

Tags: google-app-engine, unicode, python-2.7, jinja2, webapp2

I get a strange error message when trying to read non-ascii from the datastore:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-www/events.355951895377615944/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-www/events.355951895377615944/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-www/events.355951895377615944/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-www/events.355951895377615944/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-www/events.355951895377615944/handler.py", line 127, in dispatch
    response = super(NewBaseHandler, self).dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-www/events.355951895377615944/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-www/events.355951895377615944/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-www/events.355951895377615944/handler.py", line 73, in check_login
    return handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-www/events.355951895377615944/handler.py", line 526, in get
    user=user)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-www/events.355951895377615944/handler.py", line 91, in render_jinja
    **template_args))
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-www/events.355951895377615944/webapp2_extras/jinja2.py", line 158, in render_template
    return self.environment.get_template(_filename).render(**context)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp-www/events.355951895377615944/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "template_files/my_organization.html", line 148, in top-level template code
    <li id="{{ person.key.id()|makeid }}" class="level_1 inactive   leaf"><a href="" style="" class=""><ins>&nbsp;</ins><table class="leaf_info"><tbody>    <tr><td class="name">{{ person.firstname }} {{ person.lastname}} {{person.key.id()|makeid}}</td><td class="level" title="New Distributor"><span class="level_parseable">1</span>1</td><td class="downlines">0</td><td class="cc_personal"><span class="cc_personal_parseable"></span>0</td><td class="cc_downlines"><span class="cc_downlines_parseable"></span>0</td><td class="cc_activity"><span class="cc_activity_parseable"></span>0</td><td class="cc_nonmanager"><span class="cc_nonmanager_parseable"></span>0</td><td class="cc_total"><span class="cc_total_parseable"></span>0</td></tr></tbody></table></a></li>{% endfor %}
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The loop that used to work is ordinary:

```
{% for person in people %}
    <li id="{{ person.key.id()|makeid }}" class="level_1 inactive   leaf">
<a href="" style="" class=""><ins>&nbsp;</ins><table class="leaf_info"><tbody>  <tr><td class="name">{{ person.firstname }} {{ person.lastname}} {{person.key.id()|makeid}}</td><td class="level" title="New Distributor"><span class="level_parseable">1</span>1</td><td class="downlines">0</td><td class="cc_personal"><span class="cc_personal_parseable"></span>0</td><td class="cc_downlines"><span class="cc_downlines_parseable"></span>0</td><td class="cc_activity"><span class="cc_activity_parseable"></span>0</td><td class="cc_nonmanager"><span class="cc_nonmanager_parseable"></span>0</td><td class="cc_total"><span class="cc_total_parseable"></span>0</td></tr></tbody></table></a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

What can I do to resolve this error?

My handler looks like this

```
class Myorg(NewBaseHandler):
    @user_required
    def get(self):
        user = auth_models.User.get_by_id(long(self.auth.get_user_by_session()['user_id']))
        people = auth_models.User.query(auth_models.User.sponsor == user.key).fetch()
        self.render_jinja('my_organization.html', people=people,
                              user=user)
```

And my model definition is the User model from webapp2. Here is also my custom filer makeid:

```
def makeid(n, countrycode="46"):
    countrycode = str(countrycode)
    n = str(n)
    return "%s%s%s" % (countrycode, '0'*(12-len(countrycode)-len(n)), n)
```

### Update

The workaround is strange, I just make a `.decode('utf-8')` which is shouldn't need to be doing:

```
class UpdateHandler(NewBaseHandler):

    @user_required
    def get(self):
        user = \
            auth_models.User.get_by_id(long(self.auth.get_user_by_session()['user_id'
                ]))
        sponsor = None
        if user.sponsor:
            sponsor = user.sponsor.get()
        address = None
        if user.address:
            address = user.address.decode('utf-8')
        if user.city:
            city = user.city.decode('utf-8')
        self.render_jinja('details.html', city=city, user=user, address=address, sponsor=sponsor, form=UpdateForm(obj=user))
```

Is there any way to decode the all of the variables of the user object at once instead of one by one?

Comment: Find the database entries containing 0xC3, or more generally any high-bit characters; and/or fix the code to accept the encoding you have in your database. FWIW 0xC3 is Ã in Latin-1, if that's what you have, or it could be the first character in a UTF8 sequence.

Comment: I can say that I probably don't stored Ã. Thank you for the comment but my code should handle the format from the datastore (google app engine) and there is very little code except for the template. Since the error occurs only on production I also conclude that it has something to do with what is read from the datastore ie the contents of the list named people and that is passed more or less directly from the datastore using a query in python `people = auth_models.User.query(auth_models.User.sponsor == user.key).fetch()` What happens if it's an UTF8 sequence?

Comment: Can you show the `__unicode__` method of your model? I suspect an error there...

Comment: The model definition is the User model from webapp2 ie http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/appengine/auth/models.html#webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.User

Comment: Can you include your custom filter "makeid" definition too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're attempting to interpolate a raw (byte) string into a Unicode template. This is done by attempting to decode the raw string into unicode using some encoding - here, the default 'ascii' encoding - which is failing because it's encountering a codepoint that isn't valid for ASCII.

To fix this, you need to pass only unicode strings into your template - decode the string using the correct codec before passing it in.

Comment: I added the handler code to the question and I'm passing an entity list that I iterate over in the template. The one thing I seem to be able to do is access the strings that are printed during iteration and somehow cast where I just output `{{person.firstname}}` iterating over the results from a query.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz Can you include your model definition too? If you're using a StringProperty, the strings should already be Unicode. Also, can you try splitting up the problematic template line into multiple lines, so we can see exactly which property is giving you the problem? Finally, it's not a cast - it's decoding. The difference is that decoding requires a codec.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The model definition is the User model from webapp2 http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/appengine/auth/models.html#webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.User

Answer (score 7):

The best was is to get the string converted to ASCII character set. You may use the python encode cgi function to convert to ASCII

```
s = string_1.encode("ascii", "ignore")
```

[Example](http://appengine4dummies.blogspot.com/2012/01/unicode-problem.html)

Answer (score 3):

Cast the text/HTML you pass to the template as Unicode and you should see it go away. Have had this problem before with Django templates in GAE with webapp2.